# Build failed when I try to run my flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, debugging, firebase-authentication

I attached what I got in debug console when I try to run my app.

These are my firebase dependencies

```
 firebase_core: ^1.12.0
 firebase_auth: ^3.3.8
 cloud_firestore: ^3.1.9
```

```
Launching lib\main.dart on ***** in debug mode...
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:11: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
    Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:17:9: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
  Error.throwWithStackTrace(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:12:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I have tried many methods, But they didn't work.

Comment: try flutter pub upgrade. then flutter pub get and  run again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try flutter clean and then flutter run it work for me

flutter version 2.10.4

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Upgrading Flutter work for me.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you might not finish platform-specific installation/setup for Firebase as well as Firebase plugins.

Just to verify that You can visit the [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/) website which will guide you through the installation steps for the targeting platforms for Firebase and plugin setup;

Otherwise, the flutter clean and flutter pub get should do the trick.

However, a problem still exists, you can restart your editor and just run the command flutter pub get/ flutter pub upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Upgrading Flutter work for me.